# Magento2 product availability

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view

Can a product be available on multiple stores with multiple views that belong to a single website, for example, on the default website I have created 2 stores: and to each of them 2 views:

```
Store 1 English
Store 1 Spanish
Store 2 English
Store 2 Spanish
```

I want some products to be available in both stores and all views, and other products to be available to just one of those stores but to both views. I can't find that functionality. It appears, that a product can be added to all the views of a store or only to one of them and there is no other option ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, thats the whole concept of Magento's Multistore functionality. 
If you just add a product it will by default be available on all stores and views (be carefull you are not talking about website's, not referring to domain but in the store functionality within magento you have website, store and storeviews)

Then you can go to a product when its loaded switch to the store or storeview you want to exclude the product and make it unavailable there.

Comment: yeah, that is what I am asking, where can i do that, can you apply a screenshot or something ? the place I found i can either choose all views, or just a single view, can't pick 2 views out of 5

Comment: Then your on the right track... you have to do it per store or per storeview.

Comment: from where i can make it per store ?

Comment: Choose Each store. Change the value. Save product and then proceed to the next store. View.